# primefaces datatable checkbox multiselection not updating

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Hi in my project:JSF2 with primefaces 5.0, I need to select multiple rows on a datatable and display some data about this selection, as far I can  do selection with checkbox, the listener on my back bean is getting fired, but the page  does not update, but if I refresh it with F5  it renders correctly. This is how the datatable is defined:

```
    <p:dataTable var="rowItem" scrollWidth="100%" scrollHeight="450"
                        value="#{fileMatchMB.homeList}"
                        selection="#{fileMatchMB.selectedHomes}"
                        rowKey="#{rowItem.pk_num}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
Home
</f:facet>
                        <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
                        ajax="true"
                        immediate="true"
                            listener="#{fileMatchMB.onRowUnSelectHome}" />
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"
                        ajax="true"
                            listener="#{fileMatchMB.onRowSelectHome}"
                        immediate="true"/>
                        <p:column selectionMode="multiple"
                            style="width:16px;text-align:center" />
                        <p:column headerText="Data Valuta">
                            <h:outputText value="#{rowItem.data}">
                                <f:converter
                                    converterId="filematch.interfaccia.CalendarConverter" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Importo">
                            <h:outputText value="#{rowItem.value}">
                                <o:converter converterId="javax.faces.Number"
                                    currencySymbol="#{rowItem.getCurrencySymbol()}" type="currency" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <!--<h:column>
                                <h:outputLabel for="hrow" value="#{rowItem.toRow()}"/> sempre 0 
                            </h:column>-->
                        <p:column headerText="Causale" styleClass="scrollableCell">
                           #{rowItem.descrizione}:
                            #{rowItem.causale}
                            </p:column>
                        <f:facet name="footer"> 
                            "#{fileMatchMB.countHome} / #{fileMatchMB.homeList.size()} #{msg.msg_records}"
                            </f:facet>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

I am a bit confused on how make the request  to the server selecting  and unselecting the rows of my datatable.

Comment: [1] debug using firebug network tab and check what comes as response when you fire the event and [2] what's your managed bean scope?

Comment: THankswhat should I look in the response, becaouse I get something inside a partial-response tag; the scope is session

Comment: check the end of the response, if it contains any error message

Comment: could you create a little project and upload it to github, so people here could download and try to fix?

Comment: firebug does not give me any error, but eclipse does,when I debug it I receive ERROR: MAC did not verify!

Comment: sorry, I have no idea

Comment: I have this problemonly in debug mode becaause there issomething that isnot trhead safe, so I do not think that is related to my original issue

Comment: check this https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2553

Comment: I solved,maybe is not the best solutionbut it works, I added onsuccess="document.forms['id'].submit()" to my p:ajax event